# AuthUserFile, malfunction with two cms

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

on a single domain I installed two cms:

- PrestaShop
- Wordpress

in this structure:
Main directory PrestaShop + folder Blog.
in blog directory i have installed Wordpress.

For a security issue I have included in the .htaccess in blogs this string:

```
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php$">

  AuthName "Protezione WordPress"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /home/[name host]/public_html/blog/wordpress.htpasswd

  Require valid-user

  ErrorDocument 401 /e.html
</FilesMatch>
```

If I go into wp-admin, I enter 404 PrestaShop.

I entered for a control:

```
die ();
```

in index.php (PrestaShop installation)
with this modification works. Why?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Which .htaccess? Where is placed?

Comment: in /home/[name host]/public_html/blog

Comment: For some reason presta shop tries to rewrite it. Can you include the `/home/[name host]/public_html/.htaccess` Especially the rewrite rules. you will need to exclude the whole `/blog/**` in some way for presta

Comment: was it working without the changes you made to the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Can you show us the Apache configuration of Prestashop?